# How to get taken time of an image from Iphone and Mac

Tags: php, exif

I have implemented a feature using php where user will upload the images.And taken date of those images will come automatically from each image. I had used `exif_read_data` function to get the data. This is working fine in all dekstop and android mobile device. Also working fine in old I Devices. But most of the new I Devices it is not working. Is there any way to get those ?
I saw on other question in stackoverflow that those data are not saving by most new I Devices because of the security.

This is the code that I am using to get the exif data

```
@exif_read_data( $singleImage['tmp_name'], 'IFD0');
```

I need those data anyhow.

Comment: If the image doesn't contain time data then you can't get it.

Comment: Is there any way to get this time. https://ibb.co/xqPNtQh. I know this is the time when image was copied into the device.